# CreateProcess() not working with lpCurrentDirectory

Tags: windows, visual-c++, createprocess

I create a process from my application using createprocess() with parameter lpCurrentDirectory but it not works. It gives error 'The system cannot find the path specified'. my code is 
`CreateProcess( "XYZ\\bin\\run.bat", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, "XYZ\\bin", &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo ) ;`
I also give full path as lpCurrentDirectory by getting the curent directory using GetCurrentDir() and add `XYZ\\bin` to current directory,but it still not work.
I want my batch file run from lpCurrentDirectory.
I don't understand how createProcess() work with lpCurrentDirectory  parameter. Is it expect Full path or relative path ?

I also tried this with hardcoding Full path but,it display same error. Actually my original code is,
`

```
char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];

if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
 {
    printf("\n error...");
 }

string path(cCurrentPath);
path += "\\XYZ\\bin";

wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;          

wstring wstringData = converter.from_bytes(path); 

TCHAR lpszClientPath[500]= TEXT("XYZ\\bin\\run.bat /y");

if(::CreateProcess(NULL, lpszClientPath, NULL, NULL, TRUE,  CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL, wstringData.c_str(), &si, &pi) > 0)
```

`.

Comment: The documentation states unambiguously that `lpCurrentDirectory` must be a full path.  Have you tried hard-coding a valid full path into your code?  Also note that you can't launch a batch file directly, you must run `cmd /c xyz\\bin\\run.bat` instead.

Comment: All that string manipulation and conversion could be causing you trouble.  Have you tried using `MessageBox(NULL, wstringData.c_str(), L"test", MB_OK)` in place of `CreateProcess` to see what string you're actually sending as the target directory?  Have you double-checked that this target directory does actually exist?  Why don't you use `GetCurrentDirectory` to get the current directory in Unicode?

Comment: NB: regardless of what your problem turns out to be, the code as written will *not* work if the directory path contains any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: thanks Harry Johnston,I try to MessageBox, it shows right path, and directory is also exist, I need to add directory path to the currentDirectory path so I use GetCurrentDir, I think it fails because my path contain spaces in path given by GetCurrentDir which is not convert properly to Unicode, it takes only the path before the space and give error 'XYZ' internal or external command not exist.Do you have any Idea?

Comment: I found if I run my program from desktop in Windows-XP, it will not work, because path of desktop is "c:\Documents and Settings\Desktop",It works fine on windows 7,I think CreateProcess() not recognize it or it is problem of converting to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/259d3fe7-1f52-4068-bb12-32788104c798/createprocess-cannot-execute-batch-file?forum=vcgeneral).  You should read the entire thread as it reiterates the answers that were given to you in a prior thread.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but I think you don't understand my requirement, my application create from for installing driver,if I not specify lpCurrentDirectory it works ok,but when I specify it,its not working. My batch file using CD command for current directory so,I need to run it from the directory which contain this batch file not from where my actual application is run.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, both in Windows 7 and Windows XP.

```
#include <Windows.h>

void showcd(wchar_t * caption)
{
    wchar_t buffer[512];

    if (GetCurrentDirectory(512, buffer) == 0)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, L"GetCurrentDirectory failed", caption, MB_OK);
        ExitProcess(err);
    }

    buffer[511] = L'\0';
    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, caption, MB_OK);
}

void parent(wchar_t * cd)
{
    wchar_t cmd[512];
    wchar_t buffer[512];

    STARTUPINFO sinfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;

    GetStartupInfo(&sinfo);

    showcd(L"Parent Process");

    if (GetCurrentDirectory(512, buffer) == 0)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, L"GetCurrentDirectory failed", L"Parent Process", MB_OK);
        ExitProcess(err);
    }

    buffer[511] = L'\0';

    wcscat_s(buffer, 512, L"\\");
    wcscat_s(buffer, 512, cd);

    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, cmd, 512) == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"GetModuleFileName failed", L"Parent Process", MB_OK);
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    cmd[511] = L'\0';

    if (!CreateProcess(
        cmd, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, buffer, &sinfo, &pinfo
        ))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateProcess failed", L"Oops", MB_OK);
        ExitProcess(err);
    }
}

int CALLBACK WinMain( 
  _In_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_  int nCmdShow
) 
{
    wchar_t * cmdline;
    for (cmdline = GetCommandLine(); *cmdline; cmdline++)
    {
        if (*cmdline == L'*') 
        {
            parent(cmdline + 1);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    showcd(L"Child Process");
    return 0;
}
```

You can test it like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6080-CDD5

 Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator

13/12/2012  09:56 a.m.    <DIR>          .
13/12/2012  09:56 a.m.    <DIR>          ..
18/05/2012  03:10 p.m.    <DIR>          Desktop
20/06/2008  11:45 a.m.    <DIR>          Favorites
19/10/2010  02:54 p.m.    <DIR>          My Documents
20/06/2008  04:15 a.m.    <DIR>          Start Menu
               1 File(s)             43 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  29,912,666,112 bytes free

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>\appendtocurrentdirectory.exe *My Documents
```

Comment: The issue is that the asker is passing a .bat file to CreateProcess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yeah, that's one problem (which was already pointed out) but it doesn't explain the path not found error. :-)

Answer (score 0):

CreateProcess is for starting processes and you must pass an executable file. You cannot pass a .bat. Instead you'd need to start cmd.exe with the /C option and pass your batch file as an argument.